# Get and display Wordpress post ID

Tags: wordpress, post, featherlight.js

here is my website : [www.skuar.com](http://www.skuar.com)
The problem is when you click on any thumbnail, it display in the modal the same post everytime.

Is my code correct?

This is my wordpress loop

```
<div id="loop">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 

    <div id="i-scroll">

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

        <?php else : ?> 
        <p class="nothing">Nothing</p> 
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

And this is my 'content'

```
<div id="post">
    <a href="#" data-featherlight="#featherlight">   

        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails');
        }
        ?>  

    </a>

<iframe class="lightbox" src="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" width="900" height="600" id="featherlight" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

In my content I try to display the post with 
but it doesn't work...

Thank you!

Comment: Ids have to be unique within an HTML document ...

Comment: so maybe it's not about the ID...right? How to display the good post?

Comment: It is very much about the ids. Opening the right lightbox with the right link is based on the ids of those elements. But because you used the same ids multiple times, the browser will only ever "find" the first one when the JS code tries to find the element by its id. You need to use unique ids. (Keeping a loop counter and appending that to a static prefix to generate the ids would be a simple way to achieve this.)